# Multiple conditions in prepare for segue not working

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am using prepare for segue to send data between view controllers, The first if condition works when the identifier is "ShowPost" and sends the url to the view controller. But when the identifier is "profileInfo" the segue does not send data.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "ShowPost" {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
      let _url = searchResults[indexPath.row]["link"].stringValue
      let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ShowPostViewController
      destinationController.url = _url
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "ProfileInfo" {
      if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let _userName = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["display_name"].stringValue
        // print("name dc: \(destinationController.userName)")
        let _userId = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["user_id"].stringValue
        let _userReputation = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["reputation"].stringValue
        let _ppImageString = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["profile_image"].stringValue
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileInfoViewController
        destinationController.userName = _userName
        destinationController.userId = _userId
        destinationController.userReputation = _userReputation
        destinationController.ppImageString = _ppImageString
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The else statement is added inside the first if statement and it is impossible to run.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowPost" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let _url = searchResults[indexPath.row]["link"].stringValue
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ShowPostViewController
            destinationController.url = _url
        }


    }
     else if segue.identifier == "ProfileInfo" {

            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                let _userName = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["display_name"].stringValue
                // print("name dc: \(destinationController.userName)")
                let _userId = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["user_id"].stringValue
                let _userReputation = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["reputation"].stringValue
                let _ppImageString = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["profile_image"].stringValue
                let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileInfoViewController
                destinationController.userName = _userName
                destinationController.userId = _userId
                destinationController.userReputation = _userReputation
                destinationController.ppImageString = _ppImageString


            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You else statement is inside if statement so it will never be executed.

So, put seperate another if statement.

Make sure that you have set proper identifier and class from interface builder.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but now it is not hitting any break point inside the:  if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                let _userName = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["display_name"].stringValue

Comment: Not getting what you trying to say. where you put breakpoint which is not get hitting?

Comment: from this line of code let _userName = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["display_name"].stringValue 
to the end of the if let block i.e. destinationController.ppImageString = _ppImageString

Comment: Are you calling `performsegue` from `didselectrow` delegate ?

Comment: why are you comparing `if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` this? do you want to perform segue for only specific row not for all ?

Comment: then how you storing indexPath? what you storing in it?

Comment: the numerical value of the table row, so that i can access the elements of the searchResults array by using the indexPath value as array index

Comment: Actually you should use `indexPath.row` to compare instead of  `indexPath` because indexPath is not only numeric value!

Comment: i have used indexPath in the if let statement to optional unwrap.

Comment: Are you storing something in `indexPath` before performing segue?

Comment: i am not storing anything in the indexPath before performing the segue

Comment: the what is the need `if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` of this statement ? Why are you not perform without if statement?

Comment: I guess you are not aware of the concept called optional unwrapping. Maybe this link would help you understand.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowPost" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let _url = searchResults[indexPath.row]["link"].stringValue
                let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ShowPostViewController
                destinationController.url = _url
            }
        }
            else if segue.identifier == "ProfileInfo" {
                if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    let _userName = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["display_name"].stringValue
                    // print("name dc: \(destinationController.userName)")
                    let _userId = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["user_id"].stringValue
                    let _userReputation = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["reputation"].stringValue
                    let _ppImageString = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["profile_image"].stringValue
                    let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileInfoViewController
                    destinationController.userName = _userName
                    destinationController.userId = _userId
                    destinationController.userReputation = _userReputation
                    destinationController.ppImageString = _ppImageString
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be a bit clearer with a Switch:

```
switch segue.identifier ?? "" {
    case "ShowPost":
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let _url = searchResults[indexPath.row]["link"].stringValue
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ShowPostViewController
            destinationController.url = _url
        }
    case "ProfileInfo":
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let _userName = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["display_name"].stringValue
            // print("name dc: \(destinationController.userName)")
            let _userId = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["user_id"].stringValue
            let _userReputation = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["reputation"].stringValue
            let _ppImageString = searchResults[indexPath.row]["owner"]["profile_image"].stringValue
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileInfoViewController
            destinationController.userName = _userName
            destinationController.userId = _userId
            destinationController.userReputation = _userReputation
            destinationController.ppImageString = _ppImageString
    }
    default: break
}
```

Comment: when i use switch case i am getting an error at the cases saying that: expression pattern of type string cannot match values of type "String?"

Comment: I have updated it, you can use `?? ""` for it to be a string for sure, or force unwrapp it `segue.identifier!` or set a guard at the start of the function `guard let identifier = segue.identifier else { return } ` and use `identifier` instead

Comment: It fixed the error, but it still doesn't work, when i set a breakpoint inside the ProfileInfo case it does not hit.

Comment: make sure the identifier in the storyboard is really `ProfileInfo` and not for example `profileInfo` (it is case sensitive)

Comment: it is ProfileInfo, because i copy pasted it.